# Manga where a girl reincarnates into a super tech world and she pretends to be a boy to inherit her new dad's things

Tags: story-identification, manga, mecha, reincarnation

It's about a girl who reincarnates into a super tech world. Her new dad had died protecting people and was a SS mecha pilot. She pretends to be a son to inherit all of her dad's things. She has a little space (like sky poison pearl in *Against the Gods*, etc.) where she is trained. It's all full color.

Comment: To accept a correct answer, click on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm almost tempted to ask a question as an unregistered user to see if it's possible to come back to accept an answer. I just can't help but wonder what you can actually do as an unregistered user.

Comment: @Clockwork: FWIW, I suspect you have to actually register, and then request for the accounts to be merged.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots At some point in 2021, I did create one question with a guest account in private browsing, and was indeed able to accept an answer. Satisfied with the experiment, I left the guest account abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

[*It's Not Easy To Be a Man After Traveling to the Future*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/its-not-easy-to-be-a-man-after-travelling-to-the-future)

> After dying from a strange terminal illness, Ling Lan was reborn into a world 10000 years into the future. Although she dearly wished she could just live a peaceful and uneventful life in her new healthy body, fate had other plans… Forced to disguise herself as a boy just so she could inherit her deceased father’s premium military benefits, Ling Lan’s journey to adulthood was full of challenges. After much difficulty, she finally turned sixteen when she could drop the charade. But before she could grasp her newfound freedom to get married and start her own family, her resurrected father decided to go ahead and throw her into the Federation’s top military boys’ school. With these twists of fate, Ling Lan had little choice but to walk further and further down a path of no return, one of cold and aloof dominance…

Found with a search for `manga reincarnation future Mecha "as a boy"`